VSCode remote ssh: Wrong username when trying to connect
When I try to connect to remote server, I should be prompted to add a host. That's alright. But when I try to use it, a strange prefix is added to my username.
My windows .ssh/config:
Host 192.168.1.100
  HostName 192.168.1.100
  User george

enter image description here
When I connect:
"Enter password for 1004hgeorge@192.168.1.100"
enter image description here
Where does that "1004h" come from?
I can't find a way through this because Linux wouldn't allow me to add a username that begins with a digit.
Big bug for VSCode.
Big bug. I tried reinstalling, installing older versions of VSCode/Remote-ssh.
